# Getting the Max values from a varchar field

Tags: mysql, sql, max, varchar

I have a varchar field as my Employee ID and it is formated like this:

Format: YYYY-DateHired-Number 
Example: 2012-1203-0001

But Im having hard time in inserting new record because  to insert a new incremented ID, 
I need to get the latest value in this field before I increment it.

How can I get the row with the latest/highest (MAX) Numberin the most recent year?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If two users don't have the same date-of-hire, you may try: `STR_TO_DATE('%Y-%d%m')` where, I assume you've **2012-1203** mean the *12th March, 2012*

Comment: Though, separating every column is more suitable idea. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `EmployeeID`'s format is `YYYY-MMdd-XXXX`. Try this,

```
SELECT MAX(EmployeeID)
FROM tableName
WHERE EmployeeID LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 1, 4),'%')
```

## [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c120/1)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps too:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE EmployeeID IN (SELECT MAX(EmployeeID) FROM tableName)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d100/14